# Identifying polygons without gaps using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

[image]

How to identify such parcels without gaps?

Comment: If @BERA's answer solved your problem don't forget to click the green checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 3):

1. Dissolve with output polyline
2. Use Select By Location to select polygons intersecting the polyline
3. Switch selection